# Issue in converting String datetime to timestamp In Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have done the following in derived column to convert string column to timestamp

**toTimestamp({QIR Date},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')**

i/p col has 2021-01-26 11:44:45
I am getting O/p as 2021-01-26 11:44:45.000
I need to eliminate last zeros coming.I know we can do like :
**toString(toTimestamp({QIR Date},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')**

But i need the datatype as timestamp at the end . Conversion is adding 000 at the end . Can anyone help or am I approaching this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rtrim(toTimestamp({QIR Date},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'000')

[image]